# I want to return a specific error code on access of a page

Tags: html, apache2

I would like to return an error code on accessing a page, specifically a 418 error to see how my browser/server will implement it (and in case I ever manage to wire the appropriate devices to my digital coffee/tea pot I would like to know when it's done :) )

Is this even supported on Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)?

Comment: Your question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979722/i-am-a-teapot-http-418-status-code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a simple PHP page that sends the appropriate header.

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a teapot"); exit; ?>
```

However, it's simply going to do nothing. As much as all other `4xx` status codes don't alter the page's behavior, this one will also just display the rest of the content you've sent.